# Can a socket.io/node.js server be DOSd by a client emitting a message larger than the memory size of the server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, denial-of-service

If so, how can I prevent this? Is there a maximum message size setting somewhere?

If not, what is the mechanism that prevents it?

Comment: Looks like there's an issue and pull request for this. Anyone know if it has been addressed? https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/pull/888

Comment: wow 2 years old, and still `OPEN` request

Comment: I'm kinda surprised this seems to be an outstanding issue - seems like any socket.io app in production could be taken down by a single user with more ram on their box than the server.

Comment: yes it seems like vulnerable point in socket.io but not everyone, allow handshaking to anonymous users. But then again its still a vulnerability.